# Detect which extension formats a given file type

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the fastest way to check which extension is responsible for formatting a given file type?

For example, I would like to detect which extension formats my `.scss` files. I have a few candidates and would like to know a better way than just through trial and error - disabling extensions one-by-one and see what happens (this is what I am doing right now).

This is a general question, not just about `.scss` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next version **1.31.0** there should be a command `Developer: Print Available Formatters`

It outputs all available formatters for active file to the developer tools console.